# Error when adding AUTH_USER_MODEL to settings.py in DJANGO

Tags: django, django-models, django-users

i'm getting a "simple" trouble when I try to add AUTH_USER_MODEL constant to settings.py. It returns this error, but when I look to INSTALLED_APPS the app name that I'm still working is there. Here it is:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'PMEapp',
]
```

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'PMEapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'SOSpme.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'SOSpme.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

MEDIA_URL = "imgs/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "imgs")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),
)

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

LOGIN_URL = "login"

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = ""

LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "login"

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y','%d-%m-%Y','%Y-%m-%d')
```

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "PMEapp.User"
```

This is the error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'PMEapp.User' that has not been installed
```

[My installed apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFrvs.png)

[My file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Filh8.png)

[The user model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3kW3.png) -> It is in models.py

These are the things I've tried to solve the problem:

1-Created a User file including all user types in PMEapp folder with user inside didn't work.

2-Moved User file to a folder called User, got the same error.

3-Put all user types in models.py but User(AbstractUser) was still in User.py . Didn't worked too.

4-I've added a User.py file in models folder and imported it to the file that got all the user types. Same error.

Comment: Have you ran the migration command since you created the `User` model? Run `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Yes, the error appeared when i run "python3 manage.py makemigrations". I couldn't even run the migrate.

Comment: Try removing the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` from `settings.py`, then run the migration commands.

Comment: Here's the output:

SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
PMEapp.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'PMEapp.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'auth.User.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'PMEapp.User.groups' or 'auth.User.groups'.

Comment: Can you post your entire `settings.py` please? Remove sensitive parts like passwords, API keys, etc.

Comment: I edited the post with the settings.py file. But the error was found. It was missing __init__ .py file. Thank you for the support anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to add an **init**.py file to your models directory. Try adding that and startup your Django server again. You might need to import your models in your init file, like from .models import User